# retrieve int value from async task

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, task

I have an async task in a separate project that I need to call from another project but Im not sure how to accomplish that.

The async method is

```
 public async Task<int> InsertNewPasswordResetRequest(UserPasswordReset upr)
    {

        string commandText = "Insert Into passwordresetrequests (reset_username, ResetToken, ResetRequestTime, ResetRequestTimeout) values(@username,@rt,@rrt,@rrtout);";
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
          { "@username", upr.ResetUsername },
          { "@rt", upr.ResetToken },
          { "@rrt", upr.ResetRequestTime },
          { "@rrtout", upr.ResetRequestTimeout }
        };

        return await Task.FromResult( _database.Execute(commandText, parameters, false));

    }
```

I am trying to call it from another project like so

```
 Dim success As Integer = prr.InsertNewPasswordResetRequest(upr).FromResult()
```

I know its returning a task but how do I extract the int value from it?

Comment: The function you're calling doesn't run asynchronously :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can await of your task if you want to run it async

```
Dim success As Integer = Await prr.InsertNewPasswordResetRequest(upr)
```

or run task synchronously as

```
Dim success As Integer = prr.InsertNewPasswordResetRequest(upr).Result
```

Comment: Thanks, I had that the reason it didnt work is i had to make the parent function async.

Comment: The Result property does *not* simply execute the code asynchronously. Calling the Result property can lead to the code blocking. Here's a great post on the subject: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: @NathanAldenSr You can be a bit of attentive and read the phrase `or run task synchronously as`.

Comment: Whoops, I had a typo. I meant to say that Result doesn't simply execute the code *synchronously*. SO won't let me edit the original comment. :(

Comment: @NathanAldenSr Whoops, I had a typo too. I hasn't removed Await after copy/paste.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way is to `await` the results of the `InsertNewPasswordResetRequest` method. You can also call the `Result` property on the returned `Task<int>` but that could lead to your code blocking if you're executing within a synchronization context.

`int result = await InsertNewPasswordResetRequest(...);`

An additional note: There is no need to `await Task.FromResult` in that method. Simply remove the `async` modifier from the method signature and the `await` keyword and return `Task.FromResult` directly.

An additional note: If possible, consider making `InsertNewPasswordResetRequest` non-async completely since it doesn't execute any asynchronous code.

Edit for VB.NET calling code:

`Dim result As Integer = Await InsertNewPasswordResetRequest(...)`

Comment: I think he wants the answer in `VB.NET`, even though he didn't tag it.

Comment: Ah, sorry. The question was tagged C#, so... I'll update my answer.